# how to strip text that I don't care in lex/yacc?

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I am using python lex/yacc(PLY) to analyze a text file.

Basically, only part of text in the whole text I need to care.

For example, I only care pattern(expression) like a=a+NUM in the whole text.

```
  [JUNKS] a = a + 1; [JUNKS] a = a + 2; [JUNKS]
```

The real whole text could be like this:

```
a;ldfjkadl;skfjas;lkfja; a = a+1; a;dfja;lkfja;ldfjadlf a = a + 12; a;kdfj;af
```

My rule for the expression I am interested in is like:

```
my_expr : ID EQ ID PLUS NUM
```

How can I write the correct lex/yacc rules to filter out these junk string? Please not there could be any string made with all kinds of characters except the "my_expr" rule. I did many tries but haven't found a way yet.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to do this.

Just use the "state" to skip the junks.

Answer (score 0):

I would've suggested filtering them off in the lexer but the JUNKS are a little complex. See if a grammar like this works for you :-

```
stmt: ID stmt 
    | ';' stmt
    | expr
    ;

expr: ID '=' ID '+' NUM
    ;
```